# How to access variables from a console application in a Windows Forms based application?

Tags: c#

One solution is to use EMS and communicate back the variables. Any other possible way?

Comment: Please elaborate more on your question otherwise it will be difficult to give you clear answer.

Comment: Are you invoking the console application from the Windows Form or are they completely not tied together?

Comment: I have a console based application which creates a non-static class object say obj1. Now I have a seperate forms based project used to monitor variables in obj1. If it would have been a class library i can add the corresponding dll but how to go about in case of console application.

Comment: One existing solution uses remoting to communicate back the variables. But is there any other easy way ?

Comment: I think the following page will help you out a lot with this: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/csharpgeneral/thread/b5462f85-55b6-4629-a401-fb5885360630

Comment: Is it an option to invoke the console application from your Windows Form? Is so, you could just redirect STDIN/STDOUT and your life will be very easy.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to implement this by using:

- IPC (Inter Process Communication via [Named pipes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546085.aspx))
- Shared memory ([Memory mapped files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997372.aspx))
- Socket (TCP/IP)

Example of using WCF: [Many to One Local IPC using WCF and NetNamedPipeBindin](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WCF/wcfipcsample.aspx)

Other example: [A C# Framework for Interprocess Synchronization and Communication](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/threads/csthreadmsg.aspx)

Everything depends on what version of .Net Framework you use. If you use .net 3.0. and above then you can take a look into [WCF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.netnamedpipebinding.aspx). If not then you are on your own and you can google on keywords P/Invoke (CreateFileMapping, MapViewOfFile, CreatePipe...)

Comment: The simple one is always overlooked.  A file.

Answer (score 0):

You named it. [Remoting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kwdt6w2k%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) is your friend. Unless you are using .NET 3+, in which case [WCF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731082.aspx) should be preferred.